# Count the smiley faces in an array

Tags: python-3.x

Description:

Given an array (arr) as an argument complete the function countSmileys that should return the total number of smiling faces.

Rules for a smiling face:
-Each smiley face must contain a valid pair of eyes. Eyes can be marked as : or ;
-A smiley face can have a nose but it does not have to. Valid characters for a nose are - or ~
-Every smiling face must have a smiling mouth that should be marked with either ) or D.

Valid smiley face examples:
:) :D ;-D :~)
Invalid smiley faces:
;( :> :} :]

here is my code:

```
   def count_smileys(arr):
        if arr == []:
            return 0
        count = 0
        for c in arr:
            if c == ':)':count+=1

            if  c ==';-D': count+=1

            if c == ':~)': count+=1

            if c == ':D': count +=1

         return count
```

but am not passing all the tests

Comment: With 2 types of eyes, 3 types of noses and 2 types of mouths, you should have 2x3x2=12 test cases, the way you set up your test cases. 4 is definitely too few.

Comment: What is the array? an array of characters? Iterating over the elements in a string is going to give you one character at a time, but you are comparing against 2 to 3 chars, which will never evaluate to true.

Answer (score 2):

**Regular Expression is Best for This Problem**

```
import re
def count_smileys(arr):
    return len(re.findall('[:;][-~]?[)D]', str(arr)))
```

- **[:;]** signifies that, we want only : or ; as eyes(As per Problem).
- **[-~]?** signifies that, either we want - or ~ as nose , or we don't want it(As per Problem).

  ```
                     ? is used to match 0 or 1 occurrences.
  ```
- **[)D]** signifies that, we want ) or D as mouth(As per Problem).

findall() function searches all the valid smileys and insert it into arr , len() function counts all the smileys and returns the answer.

Comment: Although this may answer the question, it is helpful to include some explanation and context to readers.

Comment: Ok Adam , I will keep this in mind before writing some other answer.

Comment: Adam i have added explaination to the answer , Check it.

Comment: Thanks this will help people visiting the answer in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Regex might be the best solution:

```
import re
def count_smileys(text):
    return len(re.findall('[:;][-~]?[)D]', text))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def count_smileys(arr):
counter = 0
for e in arr:
    if e[0] in [':',';'] and e[-1] in ['D',')']:
        counter +=1
return counter
```

I just have a question, why does this code doesnt return the right answer to the same question as it was mentioned in the topic? Where is logic mistake in here?

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30341532)